# How to the Leaflet CoordsToLatLngs to draw a polyline onto a map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, static-methods, polyline

I have a geoJson file with an array of coordinates that I am trying to make into a polyline on a map using leaflet.

My code worked initially but I then realised that the longitude and latitudes are reversed in my geoJson file, so this was taking me to different coordinates.

I tried to reverse these using the coordsToLatLngs() method but keeping getting an error that this method isn't defined as it's static:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: coordsToLatLngs is not defined*

[This is a link to the leaflet documentation on this section] [1](https://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#geojson)https://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#geojson

Any guidance as to how I can use this method so that I can switch the long and lat around?

My code for this section:

````
var latLngCoords = coordsToLatLngs(value.coords, 0, false);
var polyline = L.polyline(latLngCoords, {color: 'red'}).addTo(mymap);
mymap.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
                            ```
````

Comment: v0.7.7 is like 8 years old; are you using different versions of the library and its documentation? Consider using v1.7.1 instead.

Comment: I was using 1.7.1, just used an old link here - managed to fix it using the answer given! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`coordsToLatLngs` is not imported to global scope

try to run like this

```
L.coordsToLatLngs(value.coords, 0, false)
```

or

```
L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(value.coords, 0, false)
```

or, there is turf.js library https://turfjs.org/docs/#flip with flip function

```
let coords = turf.lineString(latLngCoords)
let newCoords = turf.flip(coords)
```